# Moving for the first time to sql

Tags: mysql, testing, android

I have been doing the backends of my android apps with Firebase for a long time but it is not a good database so I decided to move to mySQL for my next project. Is that possible to build a free testing environement (server) that stores the database in testing and developing phases? If so what are the best tools? I am planning to ise mySQL Workbench to build the actual database. Also moving from the testing server to the actual server that is going to hold the database in release phase will need to make any changes in the database configuration or app code?

Answer (score 2):

> Is that possible to build a free testing environment (server) that stores the database in testing and developing phases? If so what are the best tools?

Of course, just download the community edition of MySQL or MariaDB and you will be able to create your DB environments both are GPL license so are completely free.

> I am planning to use MySQL Workbench to build the actual database.

Perfect, you can create and manage your different servers using workbench

> Also moving from the testing server to the actual server that is going to hold the database in release phase will need to make any changes in the database configuration or app code?

Not in the database configuration, just need to change your connection string in your app to connect to the production IP address instead of connecting to the test IP.